# Mysql "drop function if exists" fails with code 1305

Tags: mysql, sql-drop

When I try to execute the code bellow I get `mysql` error 1305:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS myFunction;
```

It only fails when function does not exist. But why? Isn't that the cleanup step before you re-create functions?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using & on what platform?  This works for me; how odd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL [bug #33813](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33813) explains that it may be due to case-sensitivity:

> Since MySQL 5.0.52, DROP FUNCTION commands taking schema-qualified function names compare the schema name on a case-sensitive basis, even when lower_case_table_names is set to 1.  This means that functions are not correctly identified.